# Apply different independent filters to the same column in a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, where-clause, entity-attribute-value

I have 2 tables, `players` and `stats`.

Table `players` have an `id` and a `name`, while the table `stats` looks like this:

```
id  | Player    | Stat           | Value
1   | 0000001   | Wins           |     5
2   | 0000001   | Loses          |     6
3   | 0000001   | Jumps          |   156
4   | 0000001   | Shots          |   580
5   | 0000002   | Wins           |    15
6   | 0000002   | Loses          |     2
7   | 0000002   | Jumps          |   530
8   | 0000002   | Shots          |  1704
```

I want to filter players that match several conditions, like, for example, players that have more than 5 wins but less than 200 jumps.

I tried this

```
SELECT players.name
FROM players
LEFT JOIN stats
  ON stats.player = players.id
WHERE (stats.stat = "Wins" AND stats.value > 5)
  AND (stats.stat = "Jumps" AND stats.value < 200)
GROUP BY players.id
```

But it returns nothing, because the `GROUP BY` goes after the `WHERE`.
I also tried using `OR`.

```
SELECT players.name
FROM players
LEFT JOIN stats
  ON stats.player = players.id
WHERE (stats.stat = "Wins" AND stats.value > 5)
   OR (stats.stat = "Jumps" AND stats.value < 200)
GROUP BY players.id
```

But in that case, it returns the players that match any of the conditions, and I only want the ones that match both conditions. In this specific example, it should only return the player with `id` `0000001`.

I know I could do it with a different `LEFT JOIN` for every different stat, but truth is the actual table is huge and has tons of diferent stats, so I don't think that is an option because it would be very slow.

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, things are liable to get very tricky

Comment: Welcome to the ugly world of EAV schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to aggregate. You can do this with two inner joins, one per condition:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM player p
INNER JOIN stats s1 ON s1.player = p.id AND s1.stat = 'Wins' AND s1.value > 5
INNER JOIN stats s2 ON s2.player = p.id AND s2.stat = 'Jumps' AND s2.value < 200
```

With an index on `stats(player, stat, value)`, this should be an efficient option.

Comment: Even better for indexing:  Get rid of `id` completely, then use `PRIMARY KEY(player, stat)`.